# Why the print method is running after end of recursion?

Tags: java

Why the output for below expression is printing -1 to 10?

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        subtractOne(10);
    }

    public static void subtractOne(int i){
        if(i>=0){
            subtractOne(i-1);
        }
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: As soon as `i` goes < 0, the recursion will reach its full depth and the recursive calls will all "unwind" (return), each function finally calling it's `println` on its value of `i`, which starts when `i` is -1.

Answer (score 1):

When you call method `subtractOne(10)`, it calls `subtractOne(9)` and so on, till the `subtractOne(-1)`, because previous i (0) is >= 0, and then in `subtractOne(-1)` "if" block fails and it just prints i, which is -1. Then this function returns to function which calls last one and that is `subtractOne(0)` which continues it's work after "if" block and prints(0) and so on till the last method prints 10.